# npm install does not work in my angular project

Tags: node.js, json, node-modules, npm-install, src

Why npm install does not work perfectly. When i create a new angular project and copy and paste the "src" file there, npm install works. But when I copy-paste the "package.json" same as src, npm install does not work.

[image: npm installation]

Comment: put your package.json file here.

Comment: Angular project comes with a package.json file u shouldn't create it yourself. thats if your using Angular CLI tool. makes sure your running npm install in the root dir of your project

Answer (score 0):

This error is mentioned in the [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#error-cannot-find-module-internalutiltypes) documentation:

> If you see the error Cannot find module 'internal/util/types', the
>   error is solved with a clean npm cache and trying to reinstall the
>   dependency you're working with.
>
> A start is to use the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo npm cache clean --force
> sudo npm i -g npm
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing modules in `node_modules` folder.
try to install with `auto-install`.

- first install the global-cli by cmd `npm install -g auto-install`
- then run `auto-install` in the directory you are working in.